# Swift IF statement to perform action only once

Tags: swift, if-statement, timer

I have an IF statement and I need it to trigger when the score >= 200 but only happen once and not repeatedly.

Here's my code:

```
if score >= 200 {

        meteRedTimer.invalidate()
        meteBlueTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 0.7, target: self, selector: #selector(self.makeBlueMete), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

    } else {    


    }
```

However this constantly starts the timer all the time when the score is => 200 and not just one timer which I understand.

If I do score = 200 this would work however there is a chance the score could jump from 190 to 210 for example depending on the game play.

How could I basically stop this IF statement once it has been triggered once?

Comment: i unable to reach your goal could you explained for what you want to do?

Comment: Can you maybe give a little more context?

Comment: @NazmulHasan Once the IF statement has executed I want the IF statement to end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure `meteBlueTimer` is declared as optional.

```
var meteBlueTimer: Timer?
```

Then simply check if it is nil or not.

```
if score >= 200 {
    if meteBlueTimer == nil {
        meteRedTimer.invalidate()
        meteBlueTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 0.7, target: self, selector: #selector(self.makeBlueMete), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    }
} else {    
}
```

This way you only create the `meteBlueTimer` once.

Answer (score 1):

create `var didPermored = false` and inside if statement

```
if score >= 200 && !didPermormed {
    didPermormed = true
    meteRedTimer.invalidate()
    meteBlueTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 0.7, target: self, selector: #selector(self.makeBlueMete), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
} else {    

//do stuff
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Declare your timers as optional

```
var meteBlueTimer : Timer? 
var meteRedTimer : Timer?
```

Then check if the timer is not running (`nil`). Set the invalidated timers to `nil`.

```
if score >= 200 && meteBlueTimer == nil {
       meteRedTimer?.invalidate()
       meteRedTimer = nil
       meteBlueTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 0.7, target: self, selector: #selector(self.makeBlueMete), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

} else { ...
```

Comment: Good thinking :)